# Columna editable en oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, apex

tengo el siguiente problema, estoy haciendo un software simulado de un restaurante en oracle apex y en una columna puse un check para así poder obtener los seleccionados, lo que pasa es que no logro que esa columna sea la unica editable (todas o ninguna), si alguien supiera cómo resolverlo sería de gran ayuda.
Uso un interactive grid.

[image: Visualización de la pantalla]

Comment: as intentado con un dinamic action->event->selection change grid->selection type->region-> get selection region? o podrias incluir mas que una imagen para saber que estas haciendo y guiarte mejor

Comment: Ya lo logre, muchas gracias.